# How would I autocomplete each line in a textarea?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an array of ingredients:

```
var ingredients = ["Apple", "Orange", "Banana"];
```

How would I make it so that each line in a textarea would autocomplete to an ingredient.

For example, if I type "Ap" in the first line, it should suggest apple. In the next line, if I type "Or", it should suggest orange.

Please help , and thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried? Please show us your attempt then we'll help you from there.

Comment: Creating an autosuggest, with probably a "tooltip" kinda thing for the suggestions, newlines and what not, is not just a few lines of code, you're asking us to write an entire plugin, and this is not a code-writing service, you'll have to contact a developer for that, or try yourself, and ask when your attempts fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

https://jsfiddle.net/pLmr3uxz/

```js
var keysPressed = 0;
    var preventLineBreak = false;
    var match = "";
    var ingredients = ["Apple", "Orange", "Banana"];
    $('textarea').keydown(function (e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 13 && this.selectionStart != this.selectionEnd) {
            $('textarea')[0].selectionStart = $('textarea')[0].selectionEnd;
            if (preventLineBreak == true) {
                e.preventDefault();
                preventLineBreak = false;
            }
        }
        keysPressed++;
    });
    $('textarea').keyup(function (e) {
        keysPressed--;
        if(keysPressed == 0){
            var position = $('textarea')[0].selectionStart;
            if (!(/[a-zA-Z0-9-_ ]/.test(String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode)))) { return false; }
            var haveMatch = false;
            var textValue = $('textarea').val();
            var searchValueStart = textValue.slice(0, position).lastIndexOf('\n') + 1;
            var beforeSearchValue = textValue.slice(0, searchValueStart);
            var afterSearchValue = textValue.slice(position, textValue.length);
            var searchvalue = textValue.slice(searchValueStart, position);
            ingredients.forEach(function (value) {
                if (!haveMatch && searchvalue && value.slice(0, searchvalue.length).toLowerCase() == searchvalue.toLowerCase()) {
                    match = value;
                    haveMatch = true;
            }
            });
            if (match) {
                $('textarea').val(beforeSearchValue + match + afterSearchValue);
                $('textarea')[0].selectionStart = beforeSearchValue.length + searchvalue.length;
                $('textarea')[0].selectionEnd = beforeSearchValue.length + match.length;
                match = "";
                preventLineBreak = true;
            }  
        }
    });
```

```html
<textarea></textarea>
<script   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"   integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: You can use CTRL-M to insert a working code snippet right into your answer (I edited your answer with your code form the fiddle so you can see how it is formatted)

Comment: Thanks so much! This is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Glad that I could help.